# Construct a data frame which group items based on another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like that df =

```
            ID        CODE
0           id1        A 
1           id1        B 
2           id1        C 
3           id2        D 
4           id2        E 
5           id3        A
6           id3        E
7           id3        F
```

I want to create pandas data frame from df that's look like that df2 =

```
          ID      CODE1    CODE2
0         id1       A        B
1         id1       A        C
2         id1       B        C
3         id2       D        E
4         id3       A        E
5         id3       A        F
6         id3       E        F
```

I want to make pairs for code in two columns with respect to the ID
I'm new in pandas data frame and I don't have any idea how to achieve that
Note: df data frame contains thousands of records this is just example
thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), to get the community attention and faster anwser, post what code you have tried and the error you get or where you are stuck. If you have no idea how to solve your problem, I suggest you to have a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for generating the pairs and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) in pandas for the respect to the ID's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, one way to do it

```
df.groupby('ID').CODE.agg(list).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(tuple(itertools.combinations(x,2))))\
                       .stack().apply(pd.Series)\
                       .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)\
                       .rename(columns={0: 'Code1', 1:'Code2'})

    Code1   Code2
ID      
id1 A       B
id1 A       C
id1 B       C
id2 D       E
id3 A       E
id3 A       F
id3 E       F
```

Comment: woow, thank you, but i have a question, what's the meaning of \ ?

Comment: @MF `\\` is just to allow us to break the code statement in multiple lines :)